# Is there a method or library which will produce verbose and useful failed assertion result for strings comparison?

Tags: c#, unit-testing

In unit tests when I got expected and actual strings, they can be quite lengthy. A message that expected `<xxxxxx> didn't match actual <xxxxxix>` it is usually hard to read and and its difficult to find actual mistake position(s) and real difference between produced results.

Is there maybe some kind of library that produces more useful output than just 2 strings we compare in `Assert` method?

I am thinking something like file diff but in string format and more simple obviously, like positions, characters, lengths etc.

I am currently using MSTest.

Comment: NUnit assertion methods will produce results such as "Strings differ at index <n>"; thats the best I have seen.

Answer (score 2):

See [MSpec](http://codebetter.com/aaronjensen/2008/05/08/introducing-machine-specifications-or-mspec-for-short/) ([source](https://github.com/machine/machine.specifications)). For string equality, it produces messages like this:

> ```
> String lengths are both 12. Strings differ at index 10. 
> Expected: "1234567890AB" 
> But was:  "123456789ABC"
>   ------------------^
> ```